# Управление двумя аккаунтами на github.com с одного пк

Tags: github

Есть 2 аккаунта на [github.com](https://github.com/).

Хотелось бы иметь возможность **работать** как с одним, так и с другим **с одного пк**.

**Для этого:**

1. Захожу в первый аккаунт. Создаю для него ssh ключ.

   `ssh-keygen`

   `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (ввожу ключ на github в настройках акк.)
2. Захожу во второй аккаунт. В консоли создаю для него SSH ключ:

   `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "user-2-email@gmail.com"` с именем `id_rsa_user2`
3. Ключи находятся в одной папке **.ssh**. Там же создаю файл **config**:

   ```
   # Default GitHub
   Host github.com
       HostName github.com
       PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

   # User2 GitHub
   Host user2.github.com
       HostName github.com
       PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user2
   ```
4. Тест проходит:

   `ssh -T git@github.com` и `ssh -T git@user2.github.com`

   > Hi ... ! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Создаю разные папки с разными файлами. Одна папка test1 для первого аккаунта, вторая test2 соответственно для второго аккаунта user2.

Создаю соответствующие репозитории на github аккаунтах. Выбираю работу по **ssh**.

`git init ... git add . git commit ....` - после всей инициализации:

**Ввожу:**

`git remote add origin git@github.com:user1/test1.git`

или

`git remote add origin git@github.com:user2/test2.git`

После `git push -u origin master` выдает ошибки *faild to push ... src refspec master does not match any ...*

**Вопрос:** Как правильно работать с несколькими аккаунтами github с одного ПК, как правильно проводить переключение между данными аккаунтами и как правильно создавать при этот репозитории?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решение оказалось простым **`git@user...`** т.е после знака `@` указываем имя аккаунта (из **config**):

```
git remote add origin git@user1.github.com:user1/test1.git
```

или

```
git remote add origin git@user2.github.com:user2/test1.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел такой вариант:

Global config ~/.gitconfig

```
[user]
    name = John Doe
    email = john@doe.tld

[includeIf "gitdir:~/work/"]
    path = ~/work/.gitconfig
```

Work specific config ~/work/.gitconfig

```
[user]
    email = john.doe@company.tld
```

---

Как вам нравится такой вариант?