# Настройка акаунта GitHub, push от двух юрезров

Tags: git, github, git-commit

У меня в системе два акаунта **Github**(рабочий и личный).

Все пуши идут от одного юзера в личный и рабочий рипозиторий.

---

Как сделать что бы в рабочий пушил *user1* а в личный *user2*?

Comment: Возможно мой вопрос и ответ помогут Вам https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927724/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-github-com-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BA

Comment: HamSter  cпасибо Вам большое за оперативний ответ! :)